# Formatted PC wont boot from CD

Tags: operating-systems, ubuntu-server

I cleaned the HDD of an old PC with Hiren Boot CD to make a DIY server and it worked fine. I now have very clean hard drive. The problem is when I tried to put an iso of ubuntu server onto the machine through the use of booting from a disc it would not boot and gives me the error `DISK BOOT FAILURE. INSERT SYSTEM DISK AND PRESS ENTER'`. Ive tried editing the BIOS and telling it to use the cd drive. I have also tried using 3 different discs now to see if that was the issue. None of these things have helped and I wanted to know if there is anyone who has either had this problem or is more knowledgeable to tell me what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: "... INSERT SYSTEM DISK  ..." indicates the boot disk your trying to boot to isn't actually bootable.  It sounds like you need to verify your Ubuntu disk contains the required EFI drivers.  The fact `Hiren Boot CD` worked indicates this other disk should work.

Comment: Its a CD-ROM and you are trying to insert a DVD, or you failed to properly burn the ISO in the media to preserve the boot sector, or you burnt it with a higher speed than the reader is capable of reading. The BIOS must be configured properly since you were able to use Hiren Boot CD, so I suppose its not a configuration issue. Try to find out what you are doing wrong hardware-wise.

Comment: Some old devices may require several tries because the BIOS may not wait long enough for the CD/DVD-ROM to respond with the boot sector and say the boot failed right away. A head clener disk can help in those cases. Burning the media in the lowest speed available can also help it become more reliable.

Comment: @Havenard - Please clarify your comment.  I am not sure if the type of optical disk being used is really that important.

Comment: @Ramhound He said himself its an old PC. We don't have CD-ROMs nowadays that cannot read DVDs, but there used to be those. If he is inserting a DVD in a device that can only read CDs it won't work. Maybe even the architecture is wrong, it can be a 64-bit system boot disk on a CPU that can only accept 32-bit.

Comment: @Ramhound Also, the BIOS don't do retries when it fails to read the boot disk, so any problem reading the boot sector will result in failure. Ensuring the boot sector can be read without complications is essential for a reliable boot CD. This is done by burning the media in the lowest speed available in your recorder, because by doing that you make a strong track easy to read. I've delt with enough old PCs to know all that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you were able to boot to the Hiren Boot CD, you systems does sound like it is setup to be able to boot to cd and the cd drive works. It sounds like the ubuntu cd was not burned correctly

Can you boot to the Hiren cd again?
How did you burn the ISO to the CD?

IF you browse the cd on a different system, what files do you see? Just the .iso file or multiple files?

The ISO is a cd image that needs to burned to the cd in a specific way as the image contains the boot information for the cd. IF you only have the .iso file on the disk, it will not work. Depending on what OS you use to burn the ubuntu cd, there are different steps. but linux's and windows 7 and later support iso burn natively.

Comment: I burned the disk from my laptop and if i view the disk on another pc it shows up as an iso could it be a speed issue?and i used hiren twice just to make sure the HDD was clean

Comment: The write speed was the issue i moved it down to 3x and that seemed to do the trick thank you for your help